# Extraer valor de columna computed SQL Server 2016 desde C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Necesitaria extraer de una BD SQL el dato de una columna computed el problema es que nunca trabaje con este tipo de columnas computed y no se como sacar los datos de ella.
Hasta el momento Siempre trabaje con columnas no computed y para guardar el valor devuelto por la consulta solo Usaba un objeto SqlReader y cargaba un parametro de un objeto con lo que tuviese ese objeto en la tabla que queria obtener el dato.
Al implementar eso mismo para todas las columnas me funciona bien excepto para la columna computed. Como hago para obtener ese dato?
Cantidad y PrecioVenta son columnas no computed
Total es la columna computed

```js
SqlConnection con = BDUtils.GetInstance;
con.Open();
List<Datos> invoices = new List<Datos>();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(GETALL, con);

SqlDataReader registos = com.ExecuteReader();
while (regists.Read()) {
  InvoiceDetail invoiceDetail = new InvoiceDetail {
    Cantidad = int.Parse(regists["Cantidad"].ToString()),
    PrecioVenta = decimal.Parse(regists["PrecioVenta"].ToString()),
    Total = decimal.Parse(regists["Total"].ToString())
  };
  invoices.Add(invoiceDetail);
}
con.Close();
```

Una vez ejecutado este codigo reviso las propiedades Total de los objetos creados y me aparece que es 0 el valor devuelto cuando al hacer la consulta en la base de datos me muestra un numero por ejemplo 2000.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pudes definir una columna calculada cuando defines el `SELECT`

```
string GETALL = @"SELECT Cantidad, PrecioVenta, Cantidad * PrecioVenta As Total
                  FROM Tabla";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(GETALL, con);
//resto codigo
```

Defines la columna calculada en base a las columnas de la tabla, pero recuerda validar que estas sean del tipo numericos, sino vas a tener que aplicar un `CAST o CONVERT` para pasarlo al tipo correcto